# How can I compile a .NET Standard 2.0 class library by directly invoking the C# complier using only the .NET Core SDK?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, .net-standard

When compiling a .NET Standard 2.0 class library project in Visual Studio 2019, the C# compiler (`csc.exe`) gets invoked to compile the project. If I examine the build log, the command line used looks something like this (line breaks added for readability):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
/noconfig
/unsafe-
/checked-
/nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702,2008
/nostdlib+
/errorreport:prompt
/warn:4
/define:TRACE;DEBUG;NETSTANDARD;NETSTANDARD2_0
/errorendlocation
/preferreduilang:en-US

<
A whole slew of /reference: switches that point to:
    %PROGRAMFILES%\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\netstandard.library
    \2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref
>

/debug+
/debug:portable
/filealign:512
/optimize-
/out:obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\ClassLibrary1.dll
/target:library
/warnaserror-
/utf8output
/deterministic+
Class1.cs
/warnaserror+:NU1605
```

Now, assume that I am on a machine without any version of Visual Studio. Further assume that I have the .NET Core SDK unzipped into a directory on that machine. How can I recreate the above list of `/reference:` switches with the proper list of referenced assemblies? Where is the magic manifest that I can read that will let me assemble that list?

The .csproj from which the above command line was generated has the following contents:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

As one can see, there are no assembly reference tags in the project itself, so the list of references appears to be just the list of files located in the aforementioned directory. What I want to know is how that list of files was assembled to be placed in that directory for VS, and how to mimic it using only the .NET Core SDK.

Please note that there are technical reasons I need to invoke the C# compiler directly; using MSBuild in any way is not an acceptable solution to this particular problem. This means that using `dotnet build` against a .csproj file is not an option for this particular project.

Comment: "Where is the magic manifest that I can read that will let me assemble that list?" MSBuild will generate that from the `*.csproj` file. When you start a Build in Visual Studio, VS does not run `csc` directly, instead it invokes `MSBuild` on the `*.csproj` file, which in-turn runs `csc`.

Comment: @Dai I'm not certain that it does, though. The list simply seems to be the full list of files in the directory. Since the directory is in `%PROGRAMFILES%`, the files aren't copied into that directory at compile time. The .csproj file does not enumerate these references, as they're all "framework" reference assemblies, not third-party package assemblies. But fair enough. What target, then, does the generation?

Comment: You could just be lazy and reference ALL the assemblies in netstandard2.0. Overkill, sure, but it won't cause trouble unless the project explicitly uses packages for some of the references. I'm pretty sure that determining the actual folder where these assemblies are located is pure dark magic emanating directly from Mount Doom (which is to say, MSBuild determines it "somehow").

Comment: Have you tried just running msbuild on that .csproj file and seeing what it does? I'm pretty sure the magic is in that `<TargetFramework>` tag up there; you shouldn't have to manually manage that list of references, the build tools will do it for you.

Comment: Why is MSBuild unacceptable?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Therein lies the _exact_ problem I'm having. Given _only_ the SDK, the assemblies I have available include things like `System.Private.CoreLib.dll`, which the _actual_ framework doesn't have.

Comment: Yes, well, MSBuild exists for a reason. Reverse engineering its logic is always possible in theory, but not for the faint of heart, given the multitude of files it uses at various levels. You should really reconsider if those "technical reasons" for not using it really hold water and if you can't work around them somehow (build environment in a Docker container, that sort of thing). Because even if you manage to get a poor man's MSBuild working now, there's not really any reason to assume whatever logic it uses is going to remain compatible.

Comment: Folks, please, the project I'm trying to get working has some requirements to consume resources built in other (non-.NET) languages. In order to unify the build process across all languages, we've standardized on a language agnostic build tool ([Bazel](https://bazel.build), in our case). Due to Bazel's build analysis philosophy, it wants to manage and track source files, so having Bazel only know about the .csproj file by just wrapping `dotnet build` defeats its purpose.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm perfectly open to other options. If you know of a way to call MSBuild and pass in a `/resource:` switch to the C# compiler _**without**_ having those resources exist in the .csproj file, I'd be all for it. Not having the resources in the .csproj file is a requirement, because they're generated (compiled) by non-MSBuild build tools in other languages, and it's frankly unrealistic to expect the Java, Python, Ruby, and JavaScript portions of the project to adopt MSBuild as their build mechanism.

Comment: Post-process the .csproj file to have whatever resources you need before passing it off to MSBuild? It's just XML, after all. Given its flexibility this can probably also be achieved without altering the actual file by judicious use of target files, but then we're really talking about actual use of MSBuild beyond the basics and I'm no expert on that. You may want to add `msbuild` and/or `bazel` as tags and clearly describe your original problem in the question, as it smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Given that (1) we've decided to use Bazel to build the entirety of the project; (2) Bazel's .NET build rules work by directly invoking `csc.exe`, and must do so, in order to be able to analyze and detect changes in source files, and (3) any PR to those build rules, or attempts to create new ones that would be compatible with Bazel's change detection must do the same, I'm not sure if it exactly fits the description of an XY problem, but thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core, dependencies are either projects or NuGet packages. There are a couple of NuGet packages which are referenced implicitly. For example, if your target `netstandard2.0`, you will reference version 1.6.1 of the `NETStandard.Library`.

All these rules are encoded in the [dotnet/sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk) repository. This repository contains code which is shared across the .NET CLI and Visual Studio, because both products require inimate knowledge about the .NET Core build process. For example, the dependency on NETStandard.Library 1.6.1 is encoded in [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets)

The magic command you are looking for is `dotnet restore`. This will resolve all references (NuGet and project) and create files such as `obj\projects.assets.json`, which lists, all compile time assembly references for your project. There are other files, such as `{projectname}.nuget.*`, which contain related information.

So for Bazel, there are a couple of paths you could take:

- Run `dotnet restore`, and parse the output of `project.assets.json`.
- Try consume the logic in `dotnet/sdk` from Bazel, just like Visual Studio, MSBuild and the .NET CLI do. This will be hard, since `dotnet/sdk` is written in C# and MSBuild, and Bazel probably has no notion of that.
- Try to duplicate the logic in `dotnet/sdk` in Bazel. This will be an sisyphean task.